# is there any way to make Silent installation to my C# program - on Visual-Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

is there any way to make Silent installation to my C# program -  on Visual-Studio 2008

(i mean that i dont want that when the user install my program he will need to press next->next...)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a normal Visual Studio Deployment Project the `msi` can be installed silently if you pass the right [command line parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I believe `/passive` is the one you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Yip, it's called clickOnce :-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66.aspx

In solution explorer right click your Windows Presentation Foundation, Windows Forms, or console application, click publish and follow the steps, it's as easy as that.

Comment: The user still has to confirm the installation.  Its difficult to tell what the user actually wants.  This is an odd request.

Comment: As I can gather he want's to avoid the user jumping through the hoops of pressing next --> next --> Which is the case with a clickOnce application